# why always hide h2 tags also image in the div?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I need to hide a `h2` tag if there is a image , otherwise I need to show that `h2` tags. Following is my code but it always hide my `h2` tag.

```
    if ( $(".image_resize_org").has('img') ) {
        $('h2.image_resize_org_img').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('h2.image_resize_org_img').show();
    }
```

Comment: Your code is nice.Now tell wat is NOT working

Comment: I don't know, Its a wordpress site.It always hide that h2 tag if there in the image

Comment: Its good Code . What is NOT working ?

Comment: Hi, I got the answer, somebody told me to add " each " function in the code. Now its working well. This is the first time I am using" each" funtion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.each()` in  jquery

```
$('h2.image_resize_org_img').each(function() {

       if($(this).find('img').length > 0){

           $(this).hide();
       }

       else {

          $(this).show();
       }

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the first time I am using "each" function. Thanks for your value answer & new info . Its working well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : You need to iterate each `h2` tag and check if it has image or not. Alos [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/) return object and not boolean value so check length of the object returned inside if condition.

```
$(function(){
 $('h2.image_resize_org_img').each(function(){
      if($(this).has('img').length>0)
         $(this).hide();
      else
        $(this).show();
  });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6AAXM/3/)**

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the detailed answer. I will give you +1 to this .. Kevin